# How to send a boolean to python-eve?

Tags: rest, eve

I'm trying to update a boolean value using python eve, but I always receive the same error,

```
_issues: {deleted:must be of boolean type}
deleted: "must be of boolean type"
_status: "ERR"
```

I've tried sending the field as true (setting javascript type) 'True' and 'true' (as text) and 1, but the error is always the same.

```
startdate=2014-03-25T03%3A00%3A00.000Z&code=dsa&enddate=2014-03-31T03%3A00%3A00.000Z&name=sad&note=&deleted=True

startdate=2014-03-25T03%3A00%3A00.000Z&code=dsa&enddate=2014-03-31T03%3A00%3A00.000Z&name=sad&note=&deleted=true

startdate=2014-03-25T03%3A00%3A00.000Z&code=dsa&enddate=2014-03-31T03%3A00%3A00.000Z&name=sad&note=&deleted=1
```

Any idea?

Regards

Gaston

settings.py

```
entity= {
    'resource_methods': ['GET', 'POST'],
    'schema': schema,
    'datasource': {
            'filter': {'$or':[{'deleted':{'$exists':0}},{'deleted':False}]}
            }
}

schema = {
'name': {
    'type': 'string',
    'minlength': 1,
    'maxlength': 50,
    'required': True,
},
'code': {
    'type': 'string',
},
'deleted':{
    'type':'boolean',
    'default':False
}
}
```

Full Request

```
Request URL:http://localhost:5000/campaign/532f797da54d75faabdb25d5
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,no;q=0.6,es;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:112
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host:localhost:5000
If-Match:3c7bc93e3c7d60da62f350ac990c16e29b08660f
Origin:http://localhost:5000
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:5000/static/index.html
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview parsed
startdate=2014-03-25T03%3A00%3A00.000Z&code=dsa&enddate=2014-03-31T03%3A00%3A00.000Z&name=sad&note=&deleted=True
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
Access-Control-Allow-Max-Age:21600
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:HEAD, GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Length:69
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Mon, 24 Mar 2014 00:30:10 GMT
Server:Werkzeug/0.9.4 Python/2.7.5
Set-Cookie:session=eyJfcGVybWFuZW50Ijp0cn
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change your schema to coerce `deleted` value to bool, you can send `int` or `str` values and have it converted to bool on insert/update

First, create a function to convert whatever comes, to bool:

```
to_bool = lambda v: v if type(v) is bool else str(v).lower() in ['true', '1']
```

Then, change the `deleted` in the schema to use the function to coerce values, like this:

```
'deleted':{
    'type':'boolean',
    'coerce': to_bool,
    'default':False
}
```

With this, you can per example send deleted with values such as `'0'`, `0`, `'false'` or `'False'` yelding to boolean false, or `'1'`, `1`, `'true'` or `'True'` resulting in true

Answer (score 0):

This happens only when you send the request in the content type of form-data or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. In case of AJAX requests, sending boolean value works.

```
var payload = {
    "deleted": false
};

var xhr = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(payload),
    dataType: "json",
    url: "some url"
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Your payload should be a dict like:

```
payload = {"somebool": False}
```

then you convert it to a json string:

```
payload_json = json.dumps(payload)
```

which results in a lowercased bool value in a string:

```
'{"f5only": false}'
```

then you shoulc be able to post or patch it:

```
requests.post("{0}/endpoint/".format(api_server), headers=headers, data=payload_json)
```